# HTML nodes appended from PHP become child of one another

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I was designing a notification system in such way that when I call a function in php and pass necessary parameters(notification message) it would render a notification in html.

```
<?php
    function Notification($type,$notiHead,$notiBody) {
        // echo "<b>function is being executed</b>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<div class='notification $type'><strong class='notihead'>$notiHead</strong><span class='notiBody'>$notiBody</span><span class='crosserBox'><i class='fa fa-times crosser' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
    Notification("info","Congratulation!!"," this is first notification");
    Notification("neutral","alert!","This is second notification");
    Notification("danger","alert!","This is third notification");
    Notification("alert","alert!","This is fourth notification");
    Notification("alert!","This is fifth notification");
    
Notification("alert!","This is sixth notification");

?>
```

class are styled in css like:

```
.notification {
    border: 0px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    /* width: 60vw; */
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    /* margin: 0; */
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    user-select: none;
    /* display: inline-block; */
}

.crosserBox {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 0px;
    top: 0%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

So,What I want here is those notification div that is being created from PHP function should be siblings of one another.
But those divs are being child of one other. For example, first div is the parent of second div and second div is the parent of third div.
Due to this I am getting messy output in browser.
[HTML output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Ezv.png)

[Look at here, the notification divs are becoming child of one another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68ukA.png)

What I have to do so that those divs become each other's siblings.

Comment: You didn't close `</div>` in second echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you missed the closing /div here?

```
echo "<div class='notification $type'><strong class='notihead'>$notiHead</strong><span class='notiBody'>$notiBody</span><span class='crosserBox'><i class='fa fa-times crosser' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>";
```

Code in php8 would be:

```html
<?php
    function Notification($type,$notiHead,$notiBody="") {
        // echo "<b>function is being executed</b>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<div class='notification $type'><strong class='notihead'>$notiHead</strong><span class='notiBody'>$notiBody</span><span class='crosserBox'><i class='fa fa-times crosser' aria-hidden='true'></i></span></div>\n";
        echo "<br>\n";
    }
    Notification("info","Congratulation!!"," this is first notification");
    Notification("neutral","alert!","This is second notification");
    Notification("danger","alert!","This is third notification");
    Notification("alert","alert!","This is fourth notification");
    Notification("alert!","This is fifth notification");
    
Notification("alert!","This is sixth notification");

?>
```

The result is:

```html
<br><div class='notification info'><strong class='notihead'>Congratulation!!</strong><span class='notiBody'> this is first notification</span><span class='crosserBox'><i class='fa fa-times crosser' aria-hidden='true'></i></span></div>
<br>
<br><div class='notification neutral'><strong class='notihead'>alert!</strong><span class='notiBody'>This is second notification</span><span class='crosserBox'><i class='fa fa-times crosser' aria-hidden='true'></i></span></div>
<br>
<br><div class='notification danger'><strong class='notihead'>alert!</strong><span class='notiBody'>This is third notification</span><span class='crosserBox'><i class='fa fa-times crosser' aria-hidden='true'></i></span></div>
<br>
<br><div class='notification alert'><strong class='notihead'>alert!</strong><span class='notiBody'>This is fourth notification</span><span class='crosserBox'><i class='fa fa-times crosser' aria-hidden='true'></i></span></div>
<br>
<br><div class='notification alert!'><strong class='notihead'>This is fifth notification</strong><span class='notiBody'></span><span class='crosserBox'><i class='fa fa-times crosser' aria-hidden='true'></i></span></div>
<br>
<br><div class='notification alert!'><strong class='notihead'>This is sixth notification</strong><span class='notiBody'></span><span class='crosserBox'><i class='fa fa-times crosser' aria-hidden='true'></i></span></div>
<br>
```

No nested divs.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the closing div tag there, But even after fixing that  the code behave the same.

Comment: See the code I added. I tried it and worked.